# Apt-Get Update Not Working, Can't Read Log

Tags: apt

For some reason, when I try to use sudo apt-get update, it fails, and gives me this:

```
 user@my-computer:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:4 http:/old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring InRelease
Hit:5 http:/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:6 http:/deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease [2,592 B]
Hit:7 http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:8 http:/archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http:/ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http:/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http:/old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring Release
Hit:13 http:/ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:14 http:/download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  InRelease
Ign:6 http:/deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease
Hit:11 http:/screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease
Hit:15 http:/ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:17 http:/ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:18 http:/download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  Release
Hit:19 http:/ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 2,592 B in 1s (1,580 B/s)
/usr/share/appgrid/appdata/helpers.py:9: PyGIWarning: Soup was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Soup', '2.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject, Soup
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http:/deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45
W: The repository 'http:/deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease' is not signed.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 63F7D4AFF6D61D45  
W: http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http:/download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 8F0845FE77B16294429A79346BCA5E4DB84288D9 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it isn't failing. `W:` stands for a non-fatal warning, you could easily not worry about it.

Fix for Public key error:

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

`/usr/share/appgrid/appdata/helpers.py` error was thrown because an issue in the app, not apt, you can easily ignore this.

And lastly, the `weak digest algorithm` cannot be fixed as it is an issue of the developers' side, not yours.

Hope this cleared things up.